# How do I split a string with multiple separators acting only as one in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, split

I want to split a string into an array using "space and the comma" (" ,") as the separator. Through looking through some similar questions I figured out how to make them work as one separator. However I want them to work ONLY as one. So I do not want the array to be separated by only comma's or only spaces.
So I'd like the string `"txt1, txt2,txt3 txt4, t x t 5"` become the array txt1, `"txt2,txt3 txt4", "t x t 5"` 
Here is my current code which doesn't do this:

```
var array = string.split(/(?:,| )+/)
```

Here is a link to the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MSQxk/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just do: `var array = string.split(", ");`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
var array = string.split(/,\s*/);
//=> ["txt1", "txt2", "txt3", "txt4", "t x t 5"]
```

This will compensate for strings like

```
// comma separated
foo,bar

// comma and optional space
foo,bar, hello
```

If you wanted to compensate for optional whitespace on each side of the comma, you could use this:

```
// "foo,bar, hello , world".split(/\s*,\s*);
// => ['foo', 'bar', 'hello', 'world']
```